# Compare 2 Unix Files and Output Matching Lines to a New File?

Tags: linux, perl, bash, sed, awk

I have 2 nix files. All of the data is on one single line in each file. Each value is separated by a null character. Some off the values in the data match.

How would I parse this data into a new file listing only the matching values ?

I figure I could use sed to change the null characters into newlines ? From there on I'm not real sure...

Any ideas ?

Comment: Are there duplicate values within a single file?  Some sample data would help.

Comment: would positioning make any difference, or are you just looking for matching existence at any point in the file? as @JohnZwinck said, sample data would help.

Comment: The positioning makes no difference, there may be duplicate values.

Comment: `awk` is an ideal tool for this situation. If you can share some sample data then it would be helpful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `tr`, `sort` and `comm`:

Convert nulls into new lines, and sort the result:

```
$ tr '\000' '\n' < file1 | sort > file1.txt
$ tr '\000' '\n' < file2 | sort > file2.txt
```

then use `comm` to get the lines that are common to both file:

```
$ comm -1 -2 file1.txt file2.txt
<lines shown here are the common lines between file1.txt and file2.txt>
```

Answer (score 4):

If there are no duplicate values within file1 or file2, you can do this:

```
( tr '\0' '\n' < file1; tr '\0' '\n' < file2 ) | sort | uniq -c | egrep -v '^ +1'
```

This will count all of the duplicate values between the two files.

If the order of the fields is important, you can do this:

```
comm -1 -2 <(tr '\0' '\n' < file1) <(tr '\0' '\n' < file2)
```

This approach is not portable, it requires the 'process substitution' feature of Bash.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you:

```
parallel 'tr "\000" "\n" <{} | sort -u' ::: file{1,2} | sort | uniq -d
```